# Newer Distributions versus LTS Version

Tags: upgrade, repository, version-control

I sometimes use the reposistory of a newer distribution to get very actual versions of programs e.g. the mediathek; the newest is published in the utopic distribution. The advantage is, that I automatically get always the newest developed files.

When I upgrade my packages I also get all the files for the newest ubuntu version - but I want to keep my stable LTS version.

What would you recommend to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto). Checkout that wiki article.